# How to automatically create and install requirements.txt file inside the Docker Build

Tags: python, docker

I have a question: how can I create `requirements.txt` file inside my Docker build, so I don't have to update it manually at project's directory, while releasing new versions of the app?

So, what I want is basically to construct the `requirements.txt` file inside the Docker build and install it then.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM --platform=arm64 python:3.9-buster

# Initializing Project Directory
CMD mkdir /project/dir/ 

# Setting up working directory
WORKDIR /project/dir/

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip  

RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt
ADD ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt                     # error occurs at this line


COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 


RUN chmod +x ./run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./run.sh"]
```

But unfortunately there is an error occured: `failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found`.

Do you have any tips for implementation?

Comment: I'd recommend committing the `requirements.txt` file to source control.  Be intentional about updating it – you don't want your application to break because some library outside your control had an incompatible update.  Do not `RUN pip freeze` in the Dockerfile, just `COPY` the checked-in file in to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to install dependencies into your environment before freeze can actually freeze them.

So either,
In the project directory run a `pip freeze` (preferred)
Then in the dockerfile do a `pip install -r requirements.txt` instead of `pip freeze`

Or add `pip install x` where X is each of your dependencies, then freeze.

Doing the second option would be a bit "odd" considering you usually want to build the dep list first, then provide that to your build env. Not build the dep list and build sequentially.